# GlobalSign сертификат в статусе активации уже неделю

Tags: ssl, https, домен, сертификат

Прикупил домен у одного регистратора в зоне .ru, и для него можно было оформить SSL сертификат от GlobalSign бесплатно на пол года. Я его заказал, но он уже неделю в статусе активация, а сайт со статусом Certificate is not valid. Сейчас какие то задержки с активацией сертификатов или для зоны .ru вообще проблемы с SSL или какие еще нюансы?
P.S. давно не покупал домены, выпал из этой темы

Comment: Спрашивайте там где заказали, наверное?

Comment: я не уверен что проблема с регистратором доменов, слышал что GlobalSign проверяет все домены на фишинг перед установкой сертификата, а может вообще на зону .ru не дают уже и мне не ждать а брать домен в другой зоне? @andreymal